# React v4 navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation

I'm building a web app with React and I'm using React Router v4 for navigation. Basically what I want to do is, on my signup page once the promise is fulfilled (the user signing up) I want the site to go to a new page. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do that would be to render a redirect so your code might look like something like this

```
this.state = { 
  redirect: false,
}

onSubmit() {
   Promise().then(res => this.setState({ redirect: true })
}

render() {
  redirect ? <Redirect to="/path" /> : <ShowSignUpForm />
}
```

you should take a look at the docs
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect

Comment: no problem you should take a loko at the docs react router has got some pretty good ones! Good Luck